# A suitable (vps) web hosting service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting

I would like to deploy my Ruby on Rails application. 
My application needs the following *main* resources:

- Ruby 2.3.1
- PostgreSQL (as the application's database)
- Redis (required by Sidekiq)
- Sidekiq (for background jobs)
- Sidekiq-Cron (a scheduling add-on for Sidekiq)
- Puma (web server)
- Sendgrid (to send email)
- Carrierwave (image uploader)

My `Sidekiq` background jobs would fetch data from other websites using `Nokogiri`. 
`Sidekiq-Cron` ensures that my background jobs are performed at certain times (once a week, once a month, once a year). They would update data in `PostgreSQL`. 
Users are allowed to upload images on their profile pages using `Carrierwave`. 
Because of storage issues, I configured my application to accept no more than 300 users, being allowed to upload no more than 7 pictures per day.
A background job deletes pictures older than 30 days. `Sendgrid` is used to send emails for account activation

I am already informed that I should probably look for a *Virtual Private Server* Hosting service. 
Since Heroku is expensive as you scale, I am looking for a cheaper alternative, hopefully offering Dokku for a Heroku-like deployment and configuration experience. What has the market to offer?

I am also wondering if there are hosting services which suit me and that offer convenient storage solutions, as alternative to aws s3, or plain cheaper alternatives to aws s3.

My budget is about 10$ per month for the hosting service and 5$ per month for 100GB storage.

Comment: You'd need to be a little more specific about your budget. And yes, you will probably be best off with a VPS. Personally, I use [Digital Ocean](https://m.do.co/c/47a5e6c29f4c) for my hosting. They're reliable and fairly inexpensive.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original message. I think Digital Ocean is a great hosting service and a good choice. Their storage solutions seem a bit expensive, however, more expensive anyway than aws s3.

Comment: The good thing is that you can access AWS storage from anywhere else with the API. Best of both worlds.